# Has R's ifelse good performance for conditional vectorization of expensive functions?

Tags: r, performance, if-statement

I need to evaluate two functions `f` and `g` (which are both computationally expensive) element-wise conditional on the outcome of a `test`. An advantage of `ifelse` seems to be that it does vectorized testing and only returns the fitting elements from `f` and `g`. So if we have

```
ifelse(test, f(y), g(y))
```

where `y` some large vector `ifelse` returns a vector of `length(y)` with elements `f(y)` where `test==T` and `g(y)` else.

Is this done computationally efficient? It would not be, when `ifelse` first evaluates both `f` and `g` for **all** `y` and then only returns those elements of the resulting two return vectors indicated by the test result. It would be if it only evaluate `f` where `test==T`and `g` for all others; thus saving the computation time for those elements for which `f` and `g` are not returned.

Is `ifelse` the best way to do this task for expensive functions? What would be a better way perhaps?

Comment: No, `ifelse` is not computationally efficient *at all*. In fact it's its biggest shortcoming. This is because `ifelse` computes both vectors and only then assigns the `yes` and `no` branches. If the functions are expensive you will be computing them in useless cases.

Comment: `result <- numeric(length(test)); result[test] <- f(y[test]); result[!test] <- g(y[!test])`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but ``dplyr::if_else()`` does the same without evaluating both vectors

Comment: @PedroCavalcante:  No, it does some optimizations, but that's not one of them.  Rui's suggestion is how to skip evaluations.